# Accessing path to tmp directory in my component

Tags: component, joomla-2.5, development, custom-component

How can I access in a custom component the full path to `tmp` directory configured in the Joomla configuration? I have changed the `tmp` directory to be outside of the Joomla! installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.5:

```
JFactory::getConfig()->get('tmp_path')
```

or

```
JFactory::getApplication()->getCfg('tmp_path')
```

In newer versions:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->get('tmp_path')
```